# Gray scale image should be colored in qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a gray scale image with some texture in it. I want to color it with different colors based on different scenarios. When I color the image the horizontal and vertical lines are getting colored neatly.But when it comes to coloring slant lines or circles the coloring appears to be distorted. Presently I am using ShaderEffectSource and ShaderEffect containers.
Thanks in advance.

Code:
//ColorAddition.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects.private 1.12

Item {
    id: mainCont


    property variant source


    property color color: "transparent"

    property bool cached: false

    SourceProxy {
        id: sProxyId
        input: mainCont.source
        interpolation: mainCont.smooth || (mainCont.layer.enabled && mainCont.layer.smooth)
            ? SourceProxy.NearestInterpolation :  SourceProxy.LinearInterpolation
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: cacheItem
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: mainCont.cached
        smooth: true
        sourceItem: shaderItem
        live: true
        hideSource: visible
    }

    ShaderEffect {
        id: shaderItem
        property variant source: sProxyId.output
        property color color: mainCont.color
        blending: true
        supportsAtlasTextures: true

        anchors.fill: parent

        fragmentShader: "qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtGraphicalEffects/shaders/coloroverlay.frag"
    }
}
```

Sample.qml

```
Icon {
            id: iconItem
            //scale to correct size
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            height: 32

            smooth : true

            iconid: flag? icon1 : icon2

        }
        ColorAddition {
            id: topColor
            anchors.fill: iconItem
            source: iconItem
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            if(parameter !== undefined) {
                topColor.color = flag? "red" : "gold"
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using and samples of the images you are working with and the results you are getting.

Comment: It's likely a limitation of the fragment shader you are using. Meaning, resolving it would likely require changing the shader.

Comment: In that case then fragment shader always should not work properly. The ColorAddition.qml is used at many places in code and works fine over there. I found it behaving abnormally only over here(i.e sample.qml)

Comment: Sample images will help. What images are you starting with, what do you get when it doesn't work and what do you get when it does work? Not sure what SourceProxy is but that kind of interpolation on really small images could result in visual artifacts. Have you tried disabling it in this case and look at the result?

Comment: Its a commercial project so I am prohibited from sharing the images

Comment: Can you substitute different images?

Comment: I will try doing it